# Two forms for one model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a django model like this:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    attr1 = models.IntegerField()
    attr2 = models.IntegerField()
    attr3 = models.IntegerField()
```

And I want to make a form to create *Something objects*, but I want to do it using a WizardForm, so I split the 'big form' into two forms, like this:

```
class Form1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Something
        exclude = ('atrr3',)


class Form2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Something
        fields = ('atrr3',)
```

So both together make the complete model form.
So here goes my question: **is there a way to save them both together and create a single *Something object* out of them?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of googling I found the answer to my question. I'll post it for anyone that has the same problem:

If you have more than one form and you need to combine them to create objects of a model, you can do something like this:

```
data = {}
# being list_form a iterable list of forms
for form in list_form:
    data.update(form.cleaned_data)
Something.objects.create(**data)
```

I think is a simple and pretty good solution.

Comment: Can you help me more as I have got the same requirements?

Comment: This is genious. I was thinking about creating hidden fields in each form to store previous form information, but this is so much simpler!

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually try [Django's Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#how-it-works)?

As the docs state:

> Once the user has submitted all the forms and all the data has been
>   validated, the wizard processes the data – saving it to the database,
>   sending an e-mail, or whatever the application needs to do.

Though it probably makes sense to use the rewritten wizard that will be included in 1.4:

http://django-formwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

The [usage instructions](http://django-formwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#usage) are really straightforward.

Comment: nope, didn't answer my question, I'm already using FormWizard.

Comment: Then i don't understand your problem. What do you want that the wizard isn't doing? It splits the data entry into distinct steps, validates each step/form  and finally saves that data to the db. So it saves "them both together", doesn't it?